# Concurrent.futures not parallelizing loop iterations

Tags: python, loops, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use `concurrent.futures` to process a function with multiple threads to efficiently speed up the code.

I have read [their documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) and [this guide](https://rednafi.github.io/digressions/python/2020/04/21/python-concurrent-futures.html) but believe I may not be doing this correctly. [This MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should allow us to test a number of different string lengths and list sizes to compare performance:

```
import pandas as pd, tqdm, string, random
from thefuzz import fuzz, process
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def generate_string(items=10, lengths=5):
    return [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range (lengths))] * items

def matching(a, b):
    matches = {}

    scorers = {'token_sort_ratio': fuzz.token_sort_ratio, 'token_set_ratio': fuzz.token_set_ratio, 'partial_token_sort_ratio': fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio,
                'Quick': fuzz.QRatio, 'Unicode Quick': fuzz.UQRatio, 'Weighted': fuzz.WRatio, 'Unweighted': fuzz.UWRatio}

    for x in tqdm.tqdm(a):

        best = 0

        for _, scorer in scorers.items():
            res = process.extractOne(x, b, scorer=scorer)

            if res[1] > best:
                best = res[1]
                matches[x] = res
            else:
                continue

    return matches    


list_a = generate_string(100, 10)
list_b = generate_string(10, 5)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(matching, list_a, list_b)
```

This code runs with no error; how can I use multiple workers to execute these loops in parallel so that the code will run faster?

Comment: If your functions are doing CPU work then threads and futures won't give a speed up, because Python famously has a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) meaning only one thread can be executing Python code at a time.  Threads and futures can give a speedup if your functions are doing IO (e.g. network request) as some threads can proceed while others are waiting for reply from network.  To do CPU work in parallel you need to use `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from @Anentropic, I was able to use the following change with [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_a = generate_string(500, 10)
    list_b = generate_string(500, 10)

    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count()-2)
    res = pool.map(matching, zip(list_a, list_b))

    norm_res = matching([list_a, list_b])
```